# send JSON and query parameters in a same request using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection

I need to send the `JSON data and query params` in a same request, is there any way to achieve the same using `NSURLConnection`?

Help appreciated.

eg:
request:

```
username="test"&password="password"&"location"={"latitude":12,"longitude":"78"}
```

Here location is a JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can append them to the URL as parameters, as your example shows, and issue a GET, or put part or all of the parameters in the http body, and issue a POST.  Since JSON data is usually of long, indeterminate length, most people put the JSON in the body, and use parameters or http headers for the others, with POST.

Comment: Good answer. I would only add that if you are updating data on the server, you should use POST by convention. It is bad form to update data using a GET request.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: I tried posting the JSON data using NSString string with format and it is working fine!! Thank you